# How to create a sequence of bytes() with length 1

Tags: python-3.x, string, pyserial

I am writing an application in Python 3 that talks to a device over a serial port, using the pyserial module.

When writing to a device, the pyserial module expects the data to be represented as a sequence of bytes.

This works fine if I write the data all at once, but fails if I write the data byte-by-byte, with a delay after each byte. The reason I want to write byte-by-byte is when I have to deal with devices that can only process data at a low rate.

The code I am using is:

```
def write_timed(self, data):
    """Write data to serial port,
    taking into account inter-character delay and line-delay

    :param data (str): string to write; any escaped characters will be converted
        e.g. \n will be output as a newline (not as characters '\' and 'n')
    """
    # convert raw string to sequence of bytes
    data = bytes(data.encode('latin-1').decode("unicode_escape"), "latin-1")
    logging.info("TX:{}".format(repr(data)))
    # only write to device if we have something to write
    if data:
        if data and self.char_delay_s == 0:
            self.serial.write(data)
        else:
            for d in data:
                self.serial.write(d)
                time.sleep(self.char_delay_s)
        time.sleep(self.line_delay_s)
        # ensure all data has gone out
        self.serial.flush()
```

The error I get is:

```
  File "C:\projects\maintenance\protocoltest\protocoltest\device\device.py", line 65, in write_timed
    self.serial.write(d)
  File "C:\projects\newplatform\venv3_pyside2\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 301, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\projects\newplatform\venv3_pyside2\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 61, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The reason for the error is that when I execute `for d in data:`, variable d becomes an `int` instead of a sequence of bytes with length 1.

If I try to fix that using `d = bytes(d)` I get a string of zeros, the length of the value of d.

How can I write single bytes to pyserial?

If I set `self.char_delay_s` to zero, everything works fine, even strings of length 1. If I have a non-zero value, the get the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you discovered, when you index a `bytes` object you get an `int` object. The easiest thing to do is simply cast that `int` back to `bytes`:

```
for d in data:
    d = bytes([d])
    # d is now a bytes object and can be used as such
```

Alternatively, you can use slices instead of indexing:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    d = data[i : i + 1]
    # d is a bytes object because it's a slice of a bytes object
```