# Python convert bytearray into equivalent elements

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to debug someone else's code .
Reference to "port" below is pyserial port.
https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html
I have read the docs but I still cannot figure out why it give the error that it does.
I have the following relevant functions:

```
   def send_command(self, packet, resp=True, delay=0.01, print_cmd=True):
    # Send the command and data
    if (print_cmd):
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " >", packet)

    #self.port.write(bytearray.fromhex(packet))
    #------------ start debug -----------------
    for b  in bytearray.fromhex(packet):
        self.port.write(b)
        sleep(0.1)
    #------------- end debug ------------------
    sleep(delay)

    if (resp):
        return self.wait_event()
```

The above function is called like so:

```
# Send the command to get the connection stats, save the event
        statEvt = self.send_command("01FDFF00")
```

My issue is that the device I am talking to sometimes has issues receiving UART messages because it is expecting a user to type these and not a super fast automation script.
I have had success iterating through the commands with a small delay between characters.
But that was with my code.
However with this code I have tried to add the section in between the debug comments

```
 #------------ start debug -----------------
    for b  in bytearray.fromhex(packet):
        self.port.write(b)
        sleep(0.1)
    #------------- end debug ------------------
```

But I keep getting the following error:
**invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''**

So I am not sure how to modify **b** to satisfy the function.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show the print result of the packet before the error? The first print cmd?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. There is no way anyone else can possibly explain the issue, because we have no idea what class this is in, no way to know what `self.port` is or what its `.write` will do, and because we cannot see a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: Where the code says `for b  in bytearray.fromhex(packet):`, **what do you expect** will be the type and value of `b` each time through the loop? **Did you try** to verify that? What type and value does it actually have? Now, what is your understanding of how to use `self.port.write`? Finally, **where** is the error reported?

Comment: this is part of a much larger code base the script runs fine without my changes but eventually fails because the hardware devices crashes. When I add my code chagnes which is just this line the script still runs and outputs a bunch of things but I notice something I dont see before which is the error message above.

Comment: Im a low level assembly and c type of guy, python and its intricacies are a bit tough for me,  my understanding is that the function accepts hex as a string given on how the user calls it in other functions, that string is turned into an array of bytes which is written to the port. I would assume iterating through the array I could send byte by byte. But then this is when I notice the error. Eror is reported on the terminal when it hits that line

Comment: @karl knechtel its the resial port library, even  I knew that before reading the entirety of the script im looking at. I guess I will that since it seems difficult to conjecture

Comment: @EdwinFairchild: You need to provide the complete traceback. The error you're seeing isn't obviously related to *any* of your code, so it's probably hidden a layer or two down; without the traceback, we're just guessing. Side-note: When you're just going to iterate the result directly anyway, you may as well use `bytes.fromhex` instead of `bytearray.fromhex` (the latter has slightly higher overhead to support mutability, but you're not using those features, so the shorter, more efficient type is better).

Comment: `self.port.write(bytearray.fromhex(packet))` sends a byte string.  Iterating a byte string returns *integers*, not single bytes, so you can't do `for b in bytearray(...)` and get the same result.

Comment: Highly related (maybe duplicate?) question: [How to create a sequence of bytes() with length 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54334639/364696) (it's even `pyserial` focused).

Comment: @MarkTolonen I see, im not sure I understand what a "byte string"  is, sounds like an oxymoron , so would the solution be to turn those integers in a string? But then there mentions something about base 16 , so should I turn 0xFF into a string "FF"

Comment: @EdwinFairchild: "Byte string" means something of type `bytes` or `bytearray`. Unfortunately, iterating such an object doesn't return length 1 `bytes` or `bytearray`. The related question shows how you can convert back to a length 1 `bytes` to make this work though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger interesting link, maybe I should cast the integer back to a byte. Ok I have several possible solutions from you guys. Ill give it a whirl tomorrow

Comment: (Python doesn't have "casting", but you can convert back using the `.to_bytes` method of integers. There should be a canonical question for this already but I'm struggling to find it at the moment.